# Dart: Program skipping over a line

Tags: dart

I have the following code. The cleaner version using `allShaders.forEach` was not working so this is temporary; that's a different problem.

```
static loadAndCompileAll(Function onLoad, Function onFail) {
    Function functionQueue = () { onLoad(); };

    for (int i=0; i < allShaders.length; ++i){
        Shader s = allShaders[i];
        Function previous = functionQueue;
        functionQueue = () { s.loadAndCompile(() => previous(), onFail); };
    }

    functionQueue();
}
```

I was having an issue where the shader didn't seem to be loading or compiling. Debugging showed that the last line (line 7) in the for loop is not being executed. I can step through an execution of the loop, and after stepping over line 6, it would go back up to line 4. I can't figure out why.

That method is used like this at the moment:

```
Shader.loadAndCompileAll(
            () { print("Loaded shaders"); }, 
            () { print("Failed to load shaders"); }
        );
```

I did notice that looking at the local variables in the debugger, `onLoad` and `onFail` seem to show empty, i.e. in the debugger window, it shows the name `onLoad` and the value `()`. Maybe that has something to do with it? Though I can't imagine why that would cause it to skip a line, unless this is a bug. I'm new to the language and editor so I don't know if that's a result of it being an anonymous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugger seems to skip the line but when `functionQueue()` is called `loadAndCompile()` is called instead of `onLoad()`. This indicates that the assignment statement is executed.
There seems to be an issue with the debugger (I tried it with WebStorm) that the function assignment isn't recognized as a halting point. The debugger also didn't halt on the first line in `static loadAndCompileAll`.

When you format your code a little differently you can at least set breakpoints where the debugger halts when the function is actually called.

```dart
static loadAndCompileAll(Function onLoad, Function onFail) {
    Function functionQueue = () { 
      onLoad(); // set breakpoint here
    };

    for (int i=0; i < allShaders.length; ++i){
        Shader s = allShaders[i];
        Function previous = functionQueue;
        functionQueue = () { 
          s.loadAndCompile(() => previous(), onFail); // set breakpoint here
        };
    }

    functionQueue();
}
```

Can you please create a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new for this debugger issue?

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that the application is indeed calling into `functionQueue`, and I'm just not able to observe it?

Comment: When I tried it it was calling it. You can also observe that it is being called when you set the breakpoint at the line **in** the function body when the code is formatted like in my answer. When there are more statements in one line the debugger halts only at the first statement (in this case not even at the first).

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I wrote the question. I created a bug report; https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20762
If you feel any more information should be added, please let me know.